# How to delete the list of songs on iTunes

Tags: itunes

I have a little problem with my iTunes on my pc. I have to delete all the songs that are inside it but to do this job I have to delete one song at time because I don't know how I can do it in a short way. I search also on the Internet a possible solution but with no results. Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Methode A:**

- Open iTunes
- Go to Music
- Go to the "songs" area where each song is listed on one row.
- Select a song, then click Control - A (which will select all the songs in your library)
- Go to 'Edit' menu
- Select 'Delete'

**Methode B:**

- Close iTunes
- Find the iTunes folder (C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes)
- Go to the Music folder
- Delete all of it's content
- Start iTunes again, all music should be gone

*I'm not using windows so I can't double check*